# How to download a labeled version of file from VSTS using C#?

Tags: c#, tfs

I want to download a labeled version of file from TFS. I tried out many options but I found ways to download only files from TFS but not a labeled version or a changeset version.

Is there any way this can be done?

I use C# 3.5 with TFS2008. I can use C# 4 but not TFS2010.

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to do this against the C# API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post shows how to get a specific version from source control using C# and the TFS API: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/tfsversioncontrol/thread/32999ee8-266e-40e7-9d62-00d3b8072e3b

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the file in Source Control Explorer, and select 'Get specific version'. You can then set the Type of version you want to get, which includes changeset and label.